# I have my iOS App Prototyped/Wireframed, how do I go about turning it into code?

Tags: ios, xcode, prototype, photoshop

First off thanks for any help in advance!

I have designed and made a prototype of my iOS application using UXPin and Invision. I am now ready to begin setting up the working product in Xcode.

I am lost as to how I should go about doing this. Do I import the PSD files into Xcode?

In short, I am looking to begin setting up my user interface in Xcode, and cannot seem to figure out how to get (for example) my prototype login screen turned into code.

Comment: If you're talking about importing graphic elements, then converting to .png is probably the best option.  As far as making the UI behaviour/controls into code or xib files or a storyboard, that really depends on what export or conversion features are in the tools you used.  (I'm not familiar with those.)

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on other tools that make it easier to transform a prototype into code? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: You could try paintcode

Comment: Thanks for the Paintcode recommendation. I used them a while back but never realized that they have an 'Import PSD' option in Paintcode 2. 

Great suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: I also have a web page design in UXPin.  I would have thought that UXPin would give us an option to export html with just the bare bones layout.  But unfortunately there's tonnes of javascript and other stuff in there that is making it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading the basics on how to develop apps. the iOS developer portal is filled with a wealth of info that you should take the time to study if you plan on getting anywhere: [Apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html)

Comment: I've read through the developer's manual several times. I have read much of the reference material on how to actually code the application. The user interface is different though. I am not using 'stock Apple elements' on a storyboard. I am using a custom UI that I built. 

My question was how to transfer this custom UI into code.

Comment: You can customise pretty much every "stock Apple element" of the UI layer. But it sounds like you're looking for something a bit more specific. You can look at solutions like PaintCode for doing this. I don't personally use it but it looks quite promising, (I am not affiliated to them in any way): http://www.paintcodeapp.com